# How to make a switch in Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In this [paper](https://research.google.com/pubs/pub46175.html),they design a network like this.

[image]

The left(green) is a normal network that mapping one feature to another feature,the right(red) side is an autoencoder(using RNN).But a **switch** is inserted.

**During training the switch is set randomly for each network.**

So the embedding vector can learn multiform information.

Using *MNIST* to make a example.
In order to learn image features,I define this network(for simplify,only use DNN).

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
trainingData = {List @@ # -> First@#} & /@ trainingData;
```

[image]

```
NetGraph[{FlattenLayer[], 8, 28*28, ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}], 
    UnitVectorLayer[10, "Input" -> "Integer"]}, {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4,NetPort["digit"] -> 5}, 
    "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"}], 
    "Output1" -> NetDecoder[{"Image", ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"}]]
```

[image]

But I want the net like this:
[image]

So the image features not only can learn information from image pixels,but only learn information about digits.

How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want that the node `3` either sees the output of node `2` or of node `5` (that both have the same dimensions) depending on a randomly chosen "switch" value.

You could add the "switch" variable as an extra input (with the same dimensions as the output of 2/5), that you set randomly to 0 or 1 for every sample (e.g. sample generator function), and then use `ThreadingLayer[#1*#2&]` and `ThreadingLayer[#1*(1-#2)&]` to set either node 2 or 5 to 0, then add the results, like this (untested):

```
NetGraph[{net1, net2, ThreadingLayer[#1*#2 &], 
  ThreadingLayer[#1*(1 - #2) &], ThreadingLayer[Plus], net3},
 {
  NetPort["Input"] -> 1, {1, NetPort["Switch"]} -> 3,
  NetPort["Input"] -> 2, {2, NetPort["Switch"]} -> 4,
  {3, 4} -> 5 -> 6 -> NetPort["Output"]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: I don‘t know how `ThreadingLayer[#1*(1 - #2) &]` determine which is #1,which is #2.If #1 means switch,it will leads problem

Comment: I think the function arguments are ordered like the inputs in the graph, i.e. for`{1, 2} -> 3` `#1` will be the output of node `1` and `#2` will be the output of node `2`